# Jmeter and drag and drop

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

How to record drag and drop action using jmeter. will it record client side activity we are testing the performance of documentum application

Comment: Are you using the [JMeter HTTP Proxy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Proxy_Server) to record your client requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag n drop is a UI action, jmeter works on network level.

Use JMeter Proxy Server, it will capture these:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

Comment: Hi we are giving Local host as the value for Proxy settings, is there anyother settings we need to do?